# Why isn't this method promoted in Go?

Tags: go

How does the following code work? My understanding is that obj1 embeds obj2 and therefore printTest is promoted such that we can call obj1.printTest() instead of needing to call it using obj1.obj2.printTest().

What happens with obj1Selector (I'm not sure what the string is even called that's in front of obj2)? Does obj1Selector embed obj2? Someone told me that obj1Selector does not embed obj2 but **implements a field called selector that has the type obj2**, but what does that mean - why isn't it embed? Why can't I call oSelector.printTest()?

```
type obj1 struct {
    obj2
}

type obj1Selector struct {
    selector obj2
}

type obj2 struct {
}

func (o obj2) printTest() {
    fmt.Println("obj2")
}

func main() {
    o := obj1{}
    o.printTest()

    oSelector := obj1Selector{}
    oSelector.selector.printTest()
    //oSelector.printTest() //Doesn't work
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, in response to your edit. Please check.

Comment: "Why can't I call oSelector.printTest()?" Because there isn't a `printTest` function for `obj1Selector` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called `embedding`.

From Golang specification:

> Go does not provide the typical, type-driven notion of subclassing, but it does have the ability to “borrow” pieces of an implementation by embedding types within a struct or interface.

In case of `obj1`, it is `embedding` type `obj2`, which means, what `obj2` can do, `obj1` can do. So you can invoke `printTest` directly on `obj1`.

While in case of `obj1Selector`, it defines a **new field** called `selector`, which has type `obj2`, So you have to invoke `printTest` on the `selector`, and not on `obj1Selector`.

You cannot call it directly on the `obj1Selector`, because this method belongs to another field in that struct, namely `selector`.

It is similar to how in java, we can have a class field with type of another class, So If you want to invoke a function defined on that field it will be `{InstanceOfThatClass}.{fieldName}.{method}`.